# Ctrl-C doesn't work with PyQt

Tags: python, pyqt

Why doesn't <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> work to break a Python program that uses PyQt?  I want to debug it and get a stack trace and for some reason, this is harder to do than with C++!

Comment: You should have used Google ;-) [Your problem explained with solution](http://www.mail-archive.com/pyqt@riverbankcomputing.com/msg13757.html)

Comment: @A A - Nice! I thought it was a Ctrl+C versus Ctrl+D situation.

Comment: @Wooble, thanks, I think it's a duplicate.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

> CTRL+C causes a signal to be sent to
>   the process. Python catches the
>   signal, and sets a global variable,
>   something like CTRL_C_PRESSED = True.
>   Then, whenever the Python interpreter
>   gets to execute a new opcode, it sees
>   the variable set and raises a
>   KeybordInterrupt.
>
> This means that CTRL+C works only if
>   the Python interpreter is spinning. If
>   the interpreter is executing an
>   extension module written in C that
>   executes a long-running operation,
>   CTRL+C won't interrupt it, unless it
>   explicitly "cooperates" with Python.
>   Eg: time.sleep() is theoretically a
>   blocking operation, but the
>   implementation of that function
>   "cooperates" with the Python
>   interpreter to make CTRL+C work.
>
> This is all by design: CTRL+C is meant
>   to do a "clean abort"; this is why it
>   gets turned into an exception by
>   Python (so that the cleanups are
>   executed during stack unwind), and its
>   support by extension modules is sort
>   of "opt-in". If you want to totally
>   abort the process, without giving it a
>   chance to cleanup, you can use CTRL+.
>
> When Python calls QApplication::exec()
>   (the C++ function), Qt doesn't know
>   how to "cooperate" with Python for
>   CTRL+C, and this is why it does not
>   work. I don't think there's a good way
>   to "make it work"; you may want to see
>   if you can handle it through a global
>   event filter.
>   —  Giovanni Bajo

Adding this to the main program solved the problem.

```
import signal

signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, signal.SIG_DFL)
```

I'm not sure what this has to do with the explanation.

Comment: I have no idea what this does, but it does work perfectly! EDIT: Read a bit about it [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/signal.html) so it says, that SIGINT (=Ctrl+C) should do the default action (=quit).

Answer (score 4):

I agree with Neil G, and would add this:

If you do *not* call QApplication.exec_() to start the event loop, and instead execute your program in an interactive python shell (using python -i), then pyqt will automatically process events whenever the interactive prompt is waiting, and Ctrl-C should again behave as expected. This is because the Qt event loop will be sharing time with the python interpreter, rather than running exclusively, allowing the interpreter a chance to catch those interrupts.